# Nginx proxy_pass custom header not sent to backend server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using  Nginx as a reverse proxy and want to send a custom header to the backend server. I am using below snippet however I don't see the header on the backend server.

```
http {
    ...
    proxy_bind                     0.0.0.0;
    proxy_buffering                on;
    proxy_cache_methods            GET HEAD;
    proxy_set_header               x-custom-identifier 2f3f3f3-g4g43g-43g3-h3h4h4;  ==> adding custom header
    ...

    server {
        set $upstream_endpoint     http://test.myserver.com:8888;
        listen                     443 ssl;
        location / {
            proxy_cache            cache;
        }
    }
}
```

Request headers that printed on backend server, custom header `x-custom-identifier` not present:

```
ERROR:root:Host: test.myserver.com:8888
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: e67e7179-2c7d-4728-9b55-a34198515f61
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

When I send the same custom header from client (Postman) it is reaching backend server.

```
ERROR:root:Host: test.myserver.com:8888
x-custom-identifier 2f3f3f3-g4g43g-43g3-h3h4h4 ========> custom header
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 7dbe4acb-a2de-469f-a84f-a6d0ed6ac156
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

How can I configure Nginx to add the custom header?

Followed below references but didn't help:

- https://serverfault.com/a/391615
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

Comment: It works if I place `proxy_set_header` in `location`.